# Python Requests - Return Response to PHP

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use Python Requests via PHP for scraping a page
**index.php**:

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];
$output = shell_exec("python /home/myusername/public_html/py/fetch.py $url");
echo $output;
```

and here is my **fetch.py**:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import requests
import sys

url = sys.argv[1]

headers = {'cache-control': 'no-cache'}

try:
    r = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
    #print r.status_code
    #sys.exit(1)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print e
    sys.exit(1)

if not r.text:
    print("Response Empty")
else:
    print(r.text)
```

I tried checking status code, it's 200. I tried checking if response is empty, it's not. But **r.text** is not printing at all.
What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you try using the `requests.get` method?

Comment: @moritzg same, empty response

Comment: Is there a reason why you use this two-step process? PHP can do this easily by itself (it will be faster too).

Comment: @BartFriederichs the page i am trying to scrape is not working with PHP CURL, don't know why. I tested with Requests, it's working fine in `IDLE`

Comment: Could you share the URL, so we can check ourselves?

Comment: Your Python code works perfectly in Python 2.7.15 on my machine.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214031/php-and-shell-exec

Comment: @BartFriederichs yes it works, but when i am executing this via PHP, it is returning empty response.. :(

Comment: I ran this through PHP as well, and it gives a `UnicodeEncodeError`.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Thanks for info it's useful, what can be the possible solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) there are some catches included in `shell_exec`

You may have to update your code a bit. There are chances that you may have error in your code, which are basically redirected to `stderr` and hence not captured in the `stdout`. Further [read this](https://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-shell-script-idiom-redirect/)

So back to your question. Edit your code

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];
$output = shell_exec("python /home/myusername/public_html/py/fetch.py $url 2>&1");
echo $output;
?>
```

Update Python code to:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import requests
import sys

url = sys.argv[1]

headers = {'cache-control': 'no-cache'}

try:
    r = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
    #print r.status_code
    #sys.exit(1)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print e
    sys.exit(1)

if not r.text:
    print("Response Empty")
else:
    print(r.text.encode('utf-8')) # changes
```

Comment: Still strange that the Python code works outside of PHP.

Comment: @BartFriederichs i guess may be some contents in the page may be encoded according to some region. We can never guess how the website behaves.

Answer (score 1):

Trying this way:

> shell_exec("python /home/myusername/public_html/py/fetch.py $url 2>&1");

you can see the errors in the python script you have.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/myusername/public_html/py/ig.py", line 21, in print(r.text) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 15318: ordinal not in range(128)`